# Change Default value of Axis 0 of a game controller

Tags: game-controller

So in 2018 I bought a wire less controller off of amazon, I used for some time on cracked Minecraft PE then left(i dont play cracked mc anymore)

Now I am looking to get it to work so I got the adapter and plugged it in, but there is a problem, on my Tab, as soon as I click something on the gamepad, everything goes right. And moving the left joystick left wasn't working but the Dpad's left button was working. I went to https://gamepad-tester.com/ to test it out on my computer. on Axis 0, the normal value coming was 1, when i move the left joystick left, it becomes 0, and the Dpad left, makes it -1. I think thats what causing the problem. Is there some way I can make it default to 0 and Left joystick going left, and left DPad gives -1, and right one gives 1, currently it gives 1 but it is the default only.

Also, i have lost the box and CD that came with it (the CD wasn't of use back then too)

here is the amazon link https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07DFHCNJN/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

Answer (score 0):

check a xinput mapper like: [x360ce](https://www.x360ce.com/). They all offer wide range of configurations.